# Azure Container Instance and Azure Storage = permission issue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-files, azure-container-instances

Iam running gitlab instance in ACI with Azure File Storage mount.

This is output of container:

```
storage_directory[/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (gitlab::gitlab-shell line 38) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: ruby_block[directory resource: /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/storage_directory.rb line 33) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: chmod: changing permissions of '/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh': Operation not permitted
---- End output of chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh ----
Ran chmod 00700 /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh returned 1
```

Is there anything that I have to do to correct permissions on Storage ? 
I see that some files are created, so problem is explicitly with this... 
I am using official image from docker hub. I dont want to use custom layer of image with correcting permissions.

Any idea?

Thanks

EDIT:
my deployment looks like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files#mount-multiple-volumes

Comment: Just for testing purposes, can you change the permissions to chmod 777 and see if it works ? can you run ls -l on the folder where you are running the script from to show what permissions it has ?

Thanks,

Comment: I run `ls -lha` from another container as --command-line param. Output is:

   `total 512
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 312 May 30 14:20 .gitconfig
   drwxrwxrwx 2 root root   0 May 30 14:20 .ssh`

I dont know if its even possible to set another permissions than 777, ssh keys are sensitive, gitlab tries to automatically change permissions to 700. It does work like this in Linux...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Storage Account - File is basically SMB protocol, SA is mounted with `root:root 777` permissions. If you need another permissions, You have to use Blob storage.

Comment: How to use blob storage (aside from REST/C#) in ACI? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951624/azure-container-instances-with-blobfuse-or-azure-storage-blobs