# Azure Container Instances with blobfuse or Azure Storage Blobs

Tags: azure, docker, azure-storage, azure-container-registry, azure-container-instances

I'm deploying to azure container instances from the azure container registry (azure cli and/or portal). Azure blobfuse (on ubuntu 18) is giving me the following error:

> device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first.

The solution to this would be to use the `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN --device /dev/fuse` flags when starting the container (docker run):

[can't open fuse device in a docker container when mounting a davfs2 volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106108/cant-open-fuse-device-in-a-docker-container-when-mounting-a-davfs2-volume)

However, the `--cap-add` flag is not supported by ACI:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/20b5c3f8-f849-4da2-92d9-374a37e6f446/addremove-linux-capabilities-for-docker-container?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

AzureFiles are too expensive for our scenario.

Any suggestion on how to use blobfuse or Azure Blob Storage (quasi-natively from nodejs) from a Docker Linux container in ACI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems it's impossible to mount blobfuse or Azure Blob Storage to Azure Container Instance. There are just four types volume that can be mount to. You can take a look at the [Azure Template for Azure Container Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/2018-10-01/containergroups), it shows the whole property of the ACI. And you can see all the volume objects [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/2018-10-01/containergroups#volume-object).

Maybe other volumes which we can mount to Docker Container will be supported in the future. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Is there an update or good news here? or is the situation still the same: no blobfuse on Azure Container Instances?

Comment: @GGleGrand It seems there is no update. Maybe you can add the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances) if you really need it.

Comment: Apparently still no changes to this limitation. The current best approach for this scenario appears to be via  Kubernetes: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver

Comment: Any updates here?